# Django QuerySet: Format query result as custom dictionary

Tags: django, django-queryset

I am working on a RBAC system for my Django-React app. I have this certain object structure that I want to generate but I am not sure how to do so directly from Django's QuerySet API.

Currently, I have this query

```
permissions |= PermissionAssignment.objects.filter(role=role['role__id']).values(
 'permission__object__id',
 'permission__object__name',
 'permission__operation__id',
 'permission__operation__name'
)
```

which returns this object on my frontend:

```
permissions: [
        {
          permission__object__id: 1,
          permission__object__name: 'Post',
          permission__operation__id: 1,
          permission__operation__name: 'Read'
        },
        {
          permission__object__id: 1,
          permission__object__name: 'Post',
          permission__operation__id: 2,
          permission__operation__name: 'Write'
        },
        {
          permission__object__id: 2,
          permission__object__name: 'Event',
          permission__operation__id: 2,
          permission__operation__name: 'Read'
        },
]
```

I do not require the permission object to have that complex structure. I only need to take hold of the object name and the operations enabled to this object for the current user. So basically, I just need it to be structured as:

```
permissions:[
 "Post": {
   operations: ['Read', 'Write']
 },
 "Event": {
   operations: ['Read']
 }
]
```

I know I can manipulate the original result on my frontend to get what I want, but I don't see that is necessary when I can format the result on the server-side level right away, except that I am not sure how to do that in Django.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to use list comprehension to achieve the desired outcome.

```
# NOTE: we use prefetch_related to avoid extra queries every time we access the object 
permissions_qs = PermissionAssignment.objects.filter(role=role['role__id']).prefetch_related('object', 'operation')

d = {}
[d.update({p.object.name: {'operations': [p.operation.name]}}) if p.object.name not in d else d[p.object.name]['operations'].append(p.operations.name) for p in permissions_qs]
```

Comment: Great I forgot about prefetch_related... but before considering this, can you take a look at my solution if that is ideal or bad practice? I will post it here as an `answer`. Thanks a heap!

Comment: If you found this answer helpful please mark as such. You answer is based off a question with parameters that the first question did not have.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the solution for what I wanted... The structure of the JSON response is different from what I defined in my question above, but I guess it is so much better.

However, I am posting the code here because I am having second thoughts with my approach i.e. I am starting to think the query is very expensive... and maybe someone can help check whether it is fine overall, or a bad practice indeed.

Code:

```
roles = RoleAssignment.objects.none()
modules = RoleModule.objects.none()
module_objects = ModuleObject.objects.none()
objects = Object.objects.none()
permissions = PermissionAssignment.objects.none()

roles = RoleAssignment.objects.filter(user=user).values('role__id', 'role__name')
for role in roles:
    modules |= RoleModule.objects.filter(role=role['role__id']).values(
        'role__id',
        'module__id',
        'module__name',
        'module__slug',
        'module__fontawesome_icon'
    )
    permissions |= PermissionAssignment.objects.filter(role=role['role__id']).values(
        'permission__object__id',
        'permission__object__name',
        'permission__operation__id',
        'permission__operation__name'
    )
for module in modules:
    module_objects |= ModuleObject.objects.filter(module=module['module__id']).values(
        'module__id',
        'module__name',
        'object__id',
        'object__name',
        'object__slug'
    )

# format modules to include respective objects and permissions
# this logic is primarily designed so that sidebar links can be...
# ...generated seamlessly thru frontend 
formatted_modules = [
    {
        "name": x['module__name'],
        "slug": x['module__slug'],
        "icon": x['module__fontawesome_icon'],
        "objects": [
            {
                "name": y['object__name'],
                "slug": y['object__slug'],
                "operations": [z['permission__operation__name'] for z in permissions if z['permission__object__id']==y['object__id']]
            }
            for y in module_objects if x['module__id']==y['module__id']
        ]
    }
    for x in modules
]
```

Then send it as response:

```
return Response({
    "modules": formatted_modules
})
```

The JSON equivalence:

```
{
  modules: [
    {
      name: 'Web Content',
      slug: 'web-content',
      icon: 'fas fa-newspaper',
      objects: [
        {
          name: 'Post',
          slug: 'post',
          operations: [
            'Read',
            'Write',
            'Modify',
            'Delete'
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'Bids and Awards',
      slug: 'bids-and-awards',
      icon: 'fas fa-project-diagram',
      objects: [
        {
          name: 'SRBP Goods & Services',
          slug: 'srbp-goods-services',
          operations: [
            'Read',
            'Write',
            'Modify',
            'Delete'
          ]
        },
        {
          name: 'SRBP Infrastructure',
          slug: 'srbp-infrastructure',
          operations: [
            'Read',
            'Write',
            'Modify',
            'Delete'
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

In my UI:
[image]